# Dynamically replacing Fragments

Tags: android, replace, fragment

I originally posted this queston on coderanch, but I didn't get responses, so I am trying my luck here.

I am trying to replace fragment1 with fragment3 by clicking on a 'Change Fragment' Button defined in fragmen2. Fragment3 will not fully replace Fragment1 completely. Instead it lines itself up underneath the text in Fragment1. I am doing something silly and I could use some pointers. I have included the code here and the output error screenshot (the gray area fragment3 doesn't completely overlay the white area fragment1). Thanks for any pointers.

I tried to upload and format all the code here, but for some reason, it tells me my code is not indented with 4 spaces and my output image is not a jpeg image.  So I got the code posted at 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/556305/Android/Mobile/Dynamically-replacing-Fragments
Sorry I couldn't post it here.

On my output, I see that fragment3.xml doesn't completely overlap fragment1.xml. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you should click on the 'right' button to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `R.id.fragment1` . You should give an Id for the `FrameLayout` and `replace` the contents of the `FrameLayout` with fragment2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked perfectly. I do have a question though. Do I need to declare fragment1 inside a Framelayout?  I tried to discard the Framelayout and just replace fragment1 by fragment3 from fragment2, but it wouldn't work without the FrameLayout.

Comment: Can you please post the solution?